# Error "Incorrect datetime value" during upgrade to version 5.5.1

Tags: mysql-5.7

I recently updated from a 2011 installation of CiviCRM 3.4.2 and Drupal 6, to Drupal 7 with CiviCRM 4.6.34.

Today I tried to upgrade from CiviCRM 4.6.34 to 5.5.1, and everything went well until 4.7.19, when I get the error inserted below.

My PHP and MySQL versions:

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

I found [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-prepare-for-your-mysql-5-7-upgrade) which might have some clues I am just not sure how to interpret it. Maybe someone else has experienced the same error?

---

### Error message

```
CiviCRM Upgrade Tasks
[Error: Upgrade DB to 4.7.19: SQL]
Error Field Error Value
Type  DB_Error
Code  -1
Message DB Error: unknown error
Mode  16
UserInfo  UPDATE civicrm_financial_trxn SET trxn_date = NULL WHERE trxn_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' [nativecode=1292 ** Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'trxn_date' at row 1]
DebugInfo UPDATE civicrm_financial_trxn SET trxn_date = NULL WHERE trxn_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' [nativecode=1292 ** Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'trxn_date' at row 1]

PEAR_Exception: DB Error: unknown error in /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php on line 921
- DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
Exception trace
# Function  Location
0 CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))  /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:921
1 PEAR_Error->__construct('DB Error: unknow…', -1, 16, Array, 'UPDATE civicrm_f…')  /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php:984
2 DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, Array, 'UPDATE civicrm_f…') /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:575
3 PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), null, -1, 16, Array, 'UPDATE civicrm_f…', 'DB_Error', true)  /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php:223
4 PEAR->__call('raiseError', Array) /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1907
5 DB_common->raiseError(-1, null, null, 'UPDATE civicrm_f…', '1292 ** Incorrec…') /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php:933
6 DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError() /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php:403
7 DB_mysqli->simpleQuery('UPDATE civicrm_f…') /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php:1216
8 DB_common->query('UPDATE civicrm_f…') /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/File.php:366
9 CRM_Utils_File::runSqlQuery('mysql://root:roo…', '-- CRM-19715 SEL…', null) /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:177
10  CRM_Upgrade_Form->source('-- CRM-19715 SEL…', true) /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:372
11  CRM_Upgrade_Form->processLocales('/var/www/public/…', '4.7.19') /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php:406
12  CRM_Upgrade_Form->processSQL('4.7.19')  /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/Base.php:80
13  CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_Base::runSql(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext), '4.7.19') /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Task.php:88
14  CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))  /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Runner.php:214
15  CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(true) /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:52
16  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()  /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/ErrorPolicy.php:106
17  CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))  /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Queue/Page/AJAX.php:54
18  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()  /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:275
19  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:84
20  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:52
21  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /var/www/public/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:445
22  civicrm_invoke('upgrade', 'queue', 'ajax', 'runNext') /var/www/public/drupal7/includes/menu.inc:527
23  menu_execute_active_handler() /var/www/public/drupal7/index.php:21
24  {main}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes that link you posted has the answer in #4. The easiest thing to do would be to remove those values from the sql_mode setting, i.e. in mysql run this command

SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;

Then it will output some string. Remove any reference to STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, NO_ZERO_DATE, and NO_ZERO_IN_DATE from that string. Then whatever is left you would assign that to sql_mode in your my.cnf file:

sql_mode="whatever is left from the string"

Then restart mysql.

FYI this would change the behavior of other databases on your server too, if you have any.

Comment: Thank you @Demerit! It worked perfectly, and the update completed all the way. My web site is on a shared server, so I can't restart MySQL and will probably have to pull down the database, update and re-upload it ...

There were a lot of warnings ("you may want to change these from "DATETIME" to "TIMESTAMP""), under /civicrm/a/#/status, so I ran [Doctor When: Temporal cleanup agent](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.doctorwhen) which seems to have fixed the issues.

Comment: I ended up doing the update locally, and uploading the database, which worked well.

Comment: Thanks, It works, it would be better if I could find this answer earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue during an upgrade from CiviCRM 5.29 to 5.51.

I took the approach of fixing the incorrect datetime values rather than changing the MySQL configuration to ignore incorrect dates.

The following SQL query should set the incorrect dates to `NULL`:

```
UPDATE civicrm_financial_trxn SET created_date=NULL WHERE created_date=0;
```

Note that you have to use `WHERE created_date=0` not `WHERE created_date='0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.